# How to determine load requirement of an Azure chatbot for choosing an appropriate App Service Plan

Tags: performance, botframework, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, performance-estimation

## RFP requirement

> We need to submit an RFP where we need to mention the App service plan for the Azure Chat Bot.

- Currently we aren't sure of the business requirements , we just know that it is a Service Bot and would be integrated with other enterprise applications and also answer FAQ.
- **On what basis could be calculate the system requirements of an Azure Chat Bot which could help us choose the relevant app service plan?**

> - *Supposing the Chatbot needs to take a load of 50 requests / second? Also, is this a very high expectation for an enterprise Chat Bot?*

Comment: Could you share more about the architecture? If it is just an echo bot it is easier to reach 50 requests per second, compared to a full blown virtual assistant with multiple LUIS / QnaMaker instances..

Comment: This is would be a full scale virtual Assistant / Transactional Service Chat bot with external Third party applications integrations and also integration with Internal Enterprize Applilcations for performing transactions. 

It would provide rich Adaptive for both Input and Output
Also support QnA Maker for FAQ.
Luis for Intent /Entity recognition.
WOuld also have it's own Sql Db connectivity.

What kind  of a App service plan would be sufficient to support a  production environment for this?

Comment: This is would be a full scale virtual Assistant / Transactional Service Chat bot with external Third party application integrations and also integration with Internal Enterprize Applilcations for performing transactions. 
-It would provide rich Adaptive for both Input and Output
-Also support QnA Maker for FAQ.
-Luis for Intent /Entity recognition.
-Would also have it's own Sql Db connectivity.
-WOuld maintain Context/State
-Would have it's own custom RBAC to provide Intent Based Authorization
-Support Logging
What kind  of a App service plan would be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

You are not locked in to the App Service Plan tier. You can scale up (or down) the plan based on usage.

- For **Development** I have found B1 to be sufficient. For Linux there are major pricing advantages to going with this over S1. For Windows, not so much.
- For **Production**, this is going to be highly dependent on your load at scale. For most normal traffic, S1 is probably sufficient. It is a good fit between performance and cost. On Linux P1v2 gives some good extra performance for not that much more money (again, not so much for Windows). **P1v2** is probably going to be the better bet for you, given that it supports higher scale via increased instance count, which you may need if your traffic is that heavy.

  - For what it's worth, I have a lab environment with 17 app services running on one S1 plan (a mix of Chatbots, QnA Maker, and Function Apps), and though I don't typically have a lot of requests per second, the ASP is coping just fine.

Beyond that, you can keep scaling up but the costs increase greatly. You can check out the pricing page [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/linux/) for more details (the link is for Linux, make sure to change this if you want Windows).

EDIT: Based on additional information about your bot, you have other things to consider that will constrain your peak loads.

- **LUIS S0** plan supports only 50 Transactions Per Second, so that will be an upper limit for you (assuming every message to the bot goes through LUIS). **F0** plan gives you only 5TPS.
- <strike>**QnA Maker** supports only 3 TPS on 100 Transactions Per Minute (Free and Standard).</strike>

  - QnA Maker limits are for portal/management API and not general querying
- I couldn't find any rates for Azure Storage (state) or App Insights (logging), but I imagine those are higher than LUIS's 50 TPS.
- You would also have to consider your RBAC and external integrations separately.

All that said, from App Service Plan itself, I still would assume **P1v2** would be more than sufficient for you. You could probably make do with **S1** as well. The good thing is that you can easily scale this plan up or down if you find it doesn't give you enough capacity.

Comment: This is would be a full scale virtual Assistant / Transactional Service Chat bot with external Third party application integrations and also integration with Internal Enterprize Applilcations for performing transactions. 

1.It would provide rich Adaptive for both Input and Output
2.Also support QnA Maker for FAQ.
3.Luis for Intent /Entity recognition.
4.Would also have it's own Sql Db connectivity.
5.WOuld maintain Context/State
6.Would have it's own custom RBAC to provide Intent Based Authorization
7.Support Logging

Comment: I added some additional comments for you. In particular, LUIS is only going to support 50 TPS max and QnA Maker 3 TPS max, so those are probably going to be your limiting factor.

Comment: @billoverton QnA maker is not limited to 3 TPS max. It depends on the App Service Plan and Cognitive Search instance which are used by QnAMaker. This could be scaled up easily, however especially Cognitive Search is the limiting factor and has more costs associated.

Comment: @Mick it appears I misread the spec chart. It appears that's just for portal requests and the management API, not the query API. I'll update my answer. Thanks. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/qna-maker/